# Injecting script from outside for local machine url request

Tags: php, apache, url, dvwa

I have setup a local apache server with php module.I deployed a dvwa in my localmachinne..I am learning about XSS(DOM) type of attack.I setup the low level security in dvwa.When i added `<script>alert()</script>`
in the url i got an alert

```
http://localhost/dvwa/vulnerabilities/xss_d/?default=English<script>alert()</script>
```

.But that was done through the browser.Is there any way i can inject alert() in an url request that is done form the browser as 
url=

http://localhost/dvwa/vulnerabilities/xss_d/?default=English.

What i mean is when i request the url  `http://localhost/dvwa/vulnerabilities/xss_d/?default=English` i need to append alert() from an external side.Is there some tools available for that.What tools or programs or methods i can use to inject script from external place to make script tags append to the url.I mean something like a man in the middle attack.I want to practise this in my local machine.I googled but i couldnt find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can intercept the request through a proxy and then inject the `alert()` into it. 
To do that you would need, [Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp/communitydownload).

Comment: Thanks @Sajeth Jonathan .This was what i was looking for.You gave me a super answer. But can you give me some blog or tutorial videos which shows how that is done

Comment: Make sure to install the Burp Suite Community Edition (it's free). Using Burp Proxy :[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCCrVtvAu2I&t=1s]. Check out the browser extension "FoxyProxy" to make it easier to set up a proxy. You can switch the proxy on and off at ease. If you come across issues with certificates when visiting https site, refer : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIRiTDk6Hss

Comment: thanks for this valuable piece of information